# setTimeout funtion and drag and drop in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have an image. When I drag drop that image in a division, only then I want setTimeout function to run. Not before dropping the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ondrop event as:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.droptarget {
    float: left; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 35px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
</div>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element";
}

function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(function(){alert("You dropped it!")}, 1000)
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sure no problem just make sure to hit the arrow up button to good review :)